# Angular 9 Multiple components

Tags: angular, components, angular9

Where should I have my `app-menu` component.
Should I add it in the `app.component.html` or render it in `index.html`?

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-menu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.component.html` you will have your component like this:

```html
<app-menu></app-menu>
```